# What is the purpose of the ?? operator in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

What are the main use of Null Coalescing Operator `??` as shown here:

```
double? num1 = 3.14157;
double num2 = num1 ?? 5.34;      
Console.WriteLine("Value of num2: {0}", num2);
```

Comment: To allow substitution of a default value when a nullable variable is null or unknown.

Comment: A lot doesn't make sense. `??` makes no sense to use on a `double` either.

Comment: Can you declare two variables of two different types with the same name? `int num1` and `double num1`?

Comment: @Joey It was used on a Nullable double, which makes sense if you want a fallback value.

Answer (score 7):

> "The `??` operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to define a default value for nullable value types or reference types. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand."

Source : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Null coalesce operator lets you write code much more succinctly: rather than using a conditional statement or a conditional expression, you write the equivalent expression in a single line.

Compare your expression to this

```
if (num1.HasValue) {
    num2 = num1.Value;
} else {
    num2 = 5.34;
}
```

this

```
num2 = num1.HasValue ? (double)num1.Value : 5.34;
```

or this:

```
num2 = num1 != null ? (double)num1 : 5.34;
```

Your expression is much easier to read than any of the above.

In addition, this operator lets you avoid introducing a temporary variable or even save you a function call in situations when `num1` is not in a variable, but comes from a function instead:

```
double num2 = getNum1() ?? 5.34;
```

vs.

```
int? tmpNum1 = getNum1();
num2 = num1.HasValue ? (double)num1.Value : 5.34;
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally use it to create objects the first time they are requested:

```
public ICommand OkCmd
{
    get { return _okCmd ?? (_okCmd = new DelegateCommand(Ok)); }
}
private DelegateCommand _okCmd;
```